# Add a delay to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

I'm trying to understand where to add code to delay the toggle of my div by 0.5 seconds. I am a beginner with JavaScript/jQuery.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }

//it is tied to this if it can help

<a onclick="toggle_visibility('section1_1_content');toggle_visibility('note1_1');"> <div id="help_tiem_section1_1" onclick="chngimg1()" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
            <p1>TEST</p1><img src="down.png" height="10px" width="15px" id="imgplus1"/>
        </div></a>
```

This works. However, I'd like to change it so that when it changes back to display none it does not delay.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Comment: Try using Google....

Comment: I put the subject title into google and came up with plenty of results. Please put a little research effort in before asking questions

Answer (score 3):

use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(yourFunction, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeout

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }, 500);
}
```

Update:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }, 500);
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that never will run, you are missing `);`

Comment: @WilfredoP added missing characters.

Comment: @jcubic This works however how do I change it so that when it changes back to display none it does not delay.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @joey simply wrap only one if branch with setTimeout.